# Three lines intersect at one point.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, triangles, circles

Could you please provide proof for the following claim?

"In the scalene triangle $ABC$, $I$ is the center of the inscribed circle and $k$ is the circumscribed circle. The half-lines $BI$ and $CI$ intersect the circle $k$ at the points $S_{b}\neq B$ and $S_{c}\neq C$. Prove that the tangent to the circle $k$ at point $A$, the line drawn which passes through point $I$ and is parallel to the side $BC$, and the line $S_{b}S_{c}$ intersect at one point."

I have little idea of how to proof this question. At first I thought of proving that $\angle CIB + \angle CIS_{b}=180^\circ$. However I got lost afterwards and currently have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S_bS_c$ and $AI$ intersect at $M$. We have:
$\angle S_bAI=\angle S_bAC+\angle IAC=\angle S_bBC+\angle BAI=\angle ABI+\angle BAI=\angle AIS_b$ , thus $S_bA=S_bI$.

Similarly, $S_cA=S_cI$ , and therefore $S_bS_c$ is the vertical bisector of $AI$.

Suppose the tangent at $A$ and the line parallel to $BC$ intersect at $T$ , we have $\angle TAI=\angle TAC+\angle IAC=\angle AIS_b+\angle S_bBC=\angle AIT$. Thus $TA=TI$ , so $T$ is also on the vertical bisector of $AI$. $\square$